# GP635T GPS-sensor output of data

Tags: c++, gps, sensors, intel-edison

I have a rather weird problem with my GP635T GPS-sensor connected to my Intel Edison. I use C++ and Eclipse to program it.

If I try to receive the data like this

```
          message = serialGPS.readStr(100);
          startPosition = message.find('$');
          endPosition = message.find("\n");

          std::cout << "Complete message: " << message << std::endl;
```

I get a long output consisting of all types of supported messages from `$GPGGA` to `$GPTXT` (see datasheet --> http://www.cypax.dk/pdf/GP-635T-121130.pdf). But I only want to work with the `$GPGLL`-messages. So I adjusted the code to find the index of the beginning of that message and the end of it:

```
          message = serialGPS.readStr(100);
          startPosition = message.find("$GPGLL");
          endPosition = message.find('$', startPosition+1);

          std::cout << "Complete message: " << message << std::endl;
```

But with that code, the variable 'message' always only consists of one single message of a random type. I don't know why that happens, because I do not touch the variable 'message' anywhere in my code.

Additionally, the same effect happens, if I delete / comment the lines with `message.find()` out. I still only get one message of a random type. Only the first code block shows the long message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem now by not receiving a whole string, but always getting a single character. With this code, it works for me.

```
        while(serialGPS.dataAvailable(10))
          {
              message += serialGPS.readStr(1);
          }
```